# HtmlUnit - login to a website but needs to redirect

Tags: redirect, web-crawler, htmlunit

I use the HtmlUnit to test login, and succeed in some websites.But I fail when encounter some websites that redirects after login.For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/forum.php");
    HtmlTextInput user = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("navbar_username");
    user.type("willow");
    HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getElementById("navbar_password");
    password.click();
    password.type("Willow1234");
    HtmlSubmitInput submit = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Log in']");
    page = (HtmlPage) submit.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(page.asText());
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Then I got this:

> Java Programming Forums - The Java Community
>
> Redirecting...
>
> Thank you for logging in, willow.
>
> Click here if your browser does not automatically redirect you.

I don't want this.How can I get the page after redirecting?

And I know that I can click "Click here if your browser does not automatically redirect you." to get the page.But there are websites that have no "Click here...".They just give you a "Redircting..." message.How can I get the page in that case?

I am new to HtmlUnit.

Thank you very much!

Comment: They are probably using a meta refresh tag. Either hard-code the URL where you want to go after login, and go there expliciely, or try to et the meta refresh tag from the page, get the URL, and go to this URL.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what is a "meta refresh tag".I am sorry about that.And how to the URL I want to go to after I get that URL?

Comment: Thanks. It works in this website.